# How can I pin plots on the map in Power BI

Tags: powerbi

How can I pin some plots and cards on power bi map. Many thanks in advance.

#### What I have[image: what I have]

#### What I need[image: what I need]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't directly 'Pin' items to the map. You'll have to arrange your other visuals to sit over the map visual. You can then multi select the visuals and group the items together. Using the selection tab, you can arrange the layer order of visual items, which will help arrange items.

[image]